# Best algorithm for analyzing unique sentences and filtering them?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, filter

I am in the middle of writing some code to filter sentences into different groups.
The sentences are formed from the descriptions of incident tickets that my servicedesk have processed.

I have to filter them based on 5 catergories; Laptop,Telephony,Network, Printer,Application.

An example of a description from the application catergory is: "Please can you install CMS on XXXX YYYYYYY laptop"

I understand that it is impossible to get this perfect. But I was wondering what the best way to tackle this is? As you can see from the example it falls into the application category but contains a keyword "laptop".

If theres any more information I can provide you with please let me know. Every little helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maintain different list or queues for different categories. 
When you receive sentence, check for keyword occurrence in that sentence and add/push to appropriate list/queue.

you can maintain a map which tells you which list/queue for which keyword.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the reach from receiving these sentences and sending/doing logic,
why not just filter them by regex?
See for example,
[Regex to find a specific word in a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289929/regex-to-find-a-specific-word-in-a-string-in-java)

e.g.

```
List<String> LaptopList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String item : sentenceList) {
    if item.matches(".*\\blaptop\\b.*"){
    LaptopList.add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! As seen in your example, there can be multiple keywords within the same sentence, making it difficult to decipher which category the sentence will belong to.

In order to get around this, I would suggest possibly using a separate priority queue for each category, containing keywords for each category in order of priority.

For example, you would have a priority queue of keywords for the Application category, and (within that priority queue) "install" would be of higher priority than "laptop" or "computer", because "install" is more closely related to applications than "laptop".

In your algorithm for choosing which category a sentence is part of, I would do a round-robin search through all five priority queues until a match is found - the highest priority match out of all five categories takes the sentence. This is one possible solution I can think of.

NOTE: For this to work properly, of course it is important to pick and choose carefully which keywords go into which categories; for example, in the Laptop category, it may seem natural to have "laptop" be the highest priority keyword - however, this would cause lots of collisions because laptop will probably be a very commonly used word in sentences. You should have very specific keywords pertaining to each category, rather than having broad/surface level keywords like "laptop" (or have "laptop" be a very low priority keyword).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a machine learning problem (text categorization) that you could solve using several algorithms: support vector machines, multinomial logistic regression, naive bayes and more.

There are many libraries which will help you, here is one (java)
http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/classify/read-me.html

Also python has a very good library:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#training-a-classifier

If you want to take this approach, you are going to need a training dataset, meaning that you need to manually label a set of documents that the algorithm will use to automatically learn which keywords are important.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the keyword "Laptop". But there is a keyword install "install" which primary tells about installation of some application.

So you can try like

```
        if( sentence.contains("install") || (sentence.contains("install") && sentence.contains("laptop") ) 
        {          
        applicationTickets.add(sentence);
        }
        else if(sentence.contains("laptop") || other conditions)
        {            
        laptopTickets.add(sentence);
        }
        else if(       )
        ..........
        else if(       )
        ..........
```

If you observe the code, the applications category is placed first because It is matching with the terms of Laptop. So through this code trying to fall that sentence into laptop category.

You can use loops for checking all the conditions. The keywords can be added to the specify list for every category.